# How to map frequencies to a new object with Collectors groupingBy?

Tags: java, collectors, groupingby

To get the description frequencies of class objects:

```
public class Tag {  
    private int excerptID;
    private String description;
}
```

I use Collectors groupingBy + counting functions:

```
Map<String, Long> frequencyMap = rawTags.stream().map(Tag::getDescription).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()));
```

But I want to return the result as a new object of the class

```
 public class Frequency {
    private String Description;
    private Long frequency;
    }
```

instead of `Map<String, Long>`. What is a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get `entrySet` of map and transform into Frequency class and collect as List.

```
rawTags.stream()
       .map(Tag::getDescription)
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()))
       .entrySet()
       .stream()
       .map(e -> new Frequency(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or using  `Collectors.collectingAndThen`

```
rawTags.stream()
    .map(Tag::getDescription)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e,
              Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(),
                                e -> new Frequency(e.get(0), Long.valueOf(e.size())))));
```

Comment: The second method with `Collectors.collectingAndThen` works very well, but in the first the last `map` gets underlined and throws message `The method map((<no type> e) -> {}) is undefined for the type Set<Map.Entry<String,Long>>`.

Comment: @krenkz Can you check again? it works for me. When updating the answer I forgot to put `.stream()` after `entrySet()`  maybe that is the issue.

Comment: sorry, my bad...I used the original version without `stream()`, it  works perfectly well, thank you!